# Steepest descent method and how to find the weighting factor

Tags: numerical-optimization

I am trying to understand the numerical method of finding a minimum, the steepest descent method.
\begin{equation}
x_1 = x_0 - \alpha \frac{df}{dx}
\end{equation}
I understand the idea behind it and how to set up the equation, but I do not get:

- How to find the "right" weighting factor $\alpha$.
- Why the next search has to occur orthogonal to the previous search direction.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Your second question is not correct; there is no such requirement. (Are you thinking perhaps of conjugate gradients?) For your first, do a Google search for "backtracking line search" and go from there.

Comment: See here. [gradient descent optimal step size](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373868/gradient-descent-optimal-step-size)

Comment: And this: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1154572/52878

Comment: Actually, I think the search directions are orthogonal if $f$ is quadratic *and* you are doing an exact line search.

Comment: Yes, the equation is quadratic... however I dont know how that has an importance. I thought one could apply this to all "reasonable" functions.

Comment: You can, but the orthogonality claim is not valid except for quadratics.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, you can see the book "Nonlinear Programming:Theory and Algorithms",written by Mokhtar S.Bazaraa and H.D.Sherali. 3rd edtion. Page389. It is zigzagging .

Comment: For step length, people usually don't search for the best step length, because it usually takes too much effort and is not necessary. We just look for a pretty good result under some conditions. For example, the Wolfe conditions and Goldstein conditions. You can find them in the book "Numerical Optimization", by Jorge Nocedal and another author.